# Slicing the last two characters off a jquery variable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

So i found a script that renders an image based on the selection made in a drop down.

however this script or something somewhere else is appending these |0 characters to the end of the image source.

this is the script in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var dropdown = '#input_1_10'; // the ID of your dropdown feild
var imageContainer = '#swatches'; // the id of the div which contains your image

$(dropdown).change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    jQuery(imageContainer).html('<img src="'+value+'" alt="" />'); 
});

});

   </script>
```

This is what i see from the inspect element window

```
<img src="http://www.whiskey3defensesolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/1-Arctic-White.jpg|0" alt="">
```

This happens on every single image i try to link with the drop down options

so what i want to do is slice off the |0 but i can't figure out how

This is on a wordpress website running Woocommerce, Woocommerce Gravity forms Add-on and Gravity forms plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split("|")` to split string.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  var dropdown = '#input_1_10'; // the ID of your dropdown feild
  var imageContainer = '#swatches'; // the id of the div which contains your image
  $(dropdown).change(function(){  
    var value = $(this).val().split("|")[0];   
    $(imageContainer).html('<img src="'+value+'" alt="" />'); 
  });    
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding

Comment: When i copy and pasted your code (still in between script tags) it didnt work.

but when i just took the split snippet and pasted it into the original it worked the best, i found that some images were getting appended by 3 characters so the slice function only worked on some.

this works on every one.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var dropdown = '#input_1_10'; // the ID of your dropdown feild
    var imageContainer = '#swatches'; // the id of the div which contains         your image

    $(dropdown).change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var value = $(this).val().split("|")[0];  //<--this should be cutting it
        jQuery(imageContainer).html('<img src="'+value+'" width="74px" height="75px" alt="" />'); 
    });

    });

     </script>

Comment: Yes it will work no matter how many characters are behind the "|". I have absolutely no idea why it does not work for you, because it should work. 
Make sure you put the code ( without document.ready() ) to your another script if you have one. Also don't use attributes to set image's width/height. Use $(imageContainer).width(75) and $..height(74) or a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using `slice` js function. It cuts the string however you want it. We will use it to cut the last 2 characters of your string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var dropdown = '#input_1_10'; // the ID of your dropdown feild
    var imageContainer = '#swatches'; // the id of the div which contains your image

    $(dropdown).change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        value = value.slice(0,-2)  //<--this should be cutting it
        jQuery(imageContainer).html('<img src="'+value+'" alt="" />'); 
    });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, i guess i was having a brain fart. Thanks

Comment: @michaelupton Looks like it was my first correct answer ever so I am very happy it helped you haha :)

Comment: @michaelupton Dont forget to click the best answer! haha

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to replace text

```js
var url = 'http://.../1-Arctic-White.jpg|0';

var newUrl = url.replace(/\|.*?$/, '');

console.log(newUrl);
```